# All k length paths from a starting vertice

Tags: algorithm

Given a directed graph G(V,E) i need to find all the different paths starting from i towards any other vertice that have exactly k length.

I know that finding all possible paths of length exactly k between 2 vertices can be done using a 3D table in O(K*V^3) and thus we could do this V times to find all the wanted paths.However i was wondering if this can be done better than O(K*V^4).

Comment: Yes. Please specify what you really want to know. Provide some details, read [ask]. Also show what you have tried and with what you are exactly struggling.

Comment: What's wrong with just a depth-first traversal of the graph?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "find"?  Because there are could be an exponential number of paths, and you certainly can't do anything with each one of them in polynomial time.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a limited [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) from the node, and limit the depth of the search to `k`.

Comment: How can you limit DFS?

Comment: Keep a depth-counter (either as some kind of static variable, or pass as an argument to the search function). When the counter reaches zero, back out and resume the search as if you got to the bottom of the sub-tree.